# Count Matching Subsequences

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, recursion

This is what I need to do:

Create a function that receives a text string, and a search string, and returns how many times the search string appears in the string, as a subsequence of its letters in order.

For example, if you receive the word "Hhoola" and the substring "hola", the answer would be 4, because you could take the first H with the first O (and with the L and with the A), the first H with the second O, the second H with the first O, or the second H with the second O. If you receive "hobla", the answer would be 1. If you receive "ohla", the answer would be 0, because after the H there is no O to complete the sequence in order.

This is what i got so far:

```html
int count = 0;

void Function(string text, string subText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == subText[0])
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subText.Length; j++)
            {
                if (text[i + j] != subText[j])
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (j == subText.Length - 1)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

string text = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
string subText = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
ReceibeText(text, subText);
```

Comment: Have you learned recursion?  Without recursion you would need a for loop for each character of the search string.

Comment: I have, but I've try so many times, but I can't get the answer to that.

Comment: You have to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this.  Code doesn't work but is close.

```
public class SubSequences
    {
        string input = "";
        string word = "";
        int count = 0;

        public void FindMatches(string input, string word)
        {
            this.input = input;
            this.word = word;
            FindMatchesRecursive(0, 0);
        }
        public void FindMatchesRecursive(int inputIndex, int wordIndex)
        {
            for (int i = inputIndex; i < input.Length - word.Length; i++ )
            {
                for (int j = wordIndex; j < input.Length - word.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (word.Substring(i) == input.Substring(j))
                    {
                        if (j == word.Length)
                        {
                            FindMatchesRecursive(i + 1, j + 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Word Matches");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```